# extract duplicate values with 3 or more duplicates in a column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract a dataframe which only shows duplicates with e.g 3 or more duplicates in a column. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'one': pd.Series(['Berlin', 'Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Stockholm','Berlin','Stockholm','Amsterdam']),
    'two': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
    'three': pd.Series([8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
})
```

Expected output:

```
    one     two   three
0  Berlin    1      8
```

The extraction should only show the row of the first duplicate.

Comment: I don't get how series "two" and "three" would result to values 1 and 4 respectively. Could you explain a bit more what you are after for?

Comment: sorry. i typed in the wrong value for "three". i edited my post. the output only shows the row of the first duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
rows = df.groupby('one').filter(lambda group: group.shape[0] >= 3).groupby('one').first()
```

Output:

```
>>> rows
           two  three
one                  
Amsterdam    7    1.0
Berlin       1    8.0
```

It works with multiple groups of 3+ duplicates, too. I tested it.